# Ubuntu Server 22.04 cannot assign static IP address using netplan

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, static-ip

I'm running *Ubuntu Server 22.04* on *Oracle VM Virtual Box* on a *Windows 10* machine, and have the *Bridged Adapter* selected under *Networking*. I'm trying to assign a static IP address, and edited my `00-installer-config.yaml` file to look like this:

```
#This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
       - 192.168.100.1/24
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.100.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.100.1]
```

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
reboot
```

After all that, I cannot access the local website when  I type `192.168.100.1` in my browser.

This is a local website and does not need to be accessed by the world.

How do I get this right?

When I login, I can see

```
IPv4 address for enp0s3: 192.168.224.121
```

while doing `ip a` it's like in the image below.

[image]

Can you help me solve this?

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so, can you post an answer to this?